# how to show admin notice in custom menu page after submitting the form?

Tags: admin

Here is my code to save data:

```
function save_new_exam(){

    extract($_POST);
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_absb_exam_setting', 
        array( 
            'name' => $name, 
            'time' => $time,
            'status' => 1, 
            'user_id' => get_current_user_id()
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
            '%s',
            '%d',
            '%d'
        ) 
    );  

    do_action( 'admin_notices', 'new_exam_created' );
}
function new_exam_created(){

    ?>
<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
    <p> Saved successfully!</p>
</div>
<?php }
```

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">
                        <label for="mail_from"><?php _e("Exam Title"); ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="name" type="text"  value="" size="40" class="regular-text">

                        <p class="description">
                            Give a Meaningful Exam Title.                       
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">
                        <label for="mail_from"><?php _e("Exam Time"); ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="time" type="text"  value="" size="40" class="regular-text">

                        <p class="description">
                            Set exam time as HH:MM:SS format.                       
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes">
        </p>
    </form>
```

When I submit the form the data is being saved but no admin notice is being displayed. what is the problem in my code? I googled for couple of hours but no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `add_action` not `do_action`. 
And if it still doesn't work, that means, your form processing code is being triggered after WP fires `admin_notices` hook.